# Checking if two images with noise are similar using Pillow

Tags: image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a dataset of images that are similar but not pixel by pixel perfect. I am trying to write a function to determine if two are similar or not using the following code below from the Pillow library. How can I de-noise an image then properly compare with a threshold. I also have to use pillow and not opencv.

Left right reflection

```
def leftRightReflected(self):
        image1 = Image.open(self.ravenFigure1.visualFilename)
        image1 = image1.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur)
        image2 = Image.open(self.ravenFigure2.visualFilename)
        image2 = image2.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur)
        left_right_mirror = image1.transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
        return ImageChops.difference(left_right_mirror,image2).getbbox() is None
```

Top down reflection

```
def topDownReflected(self):
    image1 = Image.open(self.ravenFigure1.visualFilename)
    image1 = image1.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur)
    image2 = Image.open(self.ravenFigure2.visualFilename)
    image2 = image2.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur)
    top_bottom_mirror = image1.transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)
    return ImageChops.difference(left_right_mirror,image2).getbbox() is None
```

Comment: No idea what `ImageChops` is but from [their docs](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagechops.htm#tag-ImageChops.difference) it looks like the return is just a difference image. Don't use `getbbox()`, just `sum` the difference image returned from `difference()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing two images that are not pixel perfect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46231825/comparing-two-images-that-are-not-pixel-perfect)